# Delete from array using class name

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I am creating a simple TodoList for creating and deleting tasks:

```js
let btn= document.getElementById("createButton");
let tasks= [];

//function for creating task. This is working fine
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let taskName= document.getElementById("taskName").value;
    let startTime= document.getElementById("startTime").value;
    let endTime= document.getElementById("endTime").value;
    // console.log(taskName, startTime, endTime);
    let currTask= {
        name: taskName,
        start: startTime,
        end: endTime
    }
    tasks.unshift(currTask);
    let createdTask= document.createElement('div');
    createdTask.id= taskName;
    createdTask.classList.add("mrg-auto");

    createdTask.innerHTML= `
    <p>Task name: ${taskName}</p>
    <p>Start time: ${startTime}</p>
    <p>End time: ${endTime}</p>
    <input type="submit" class="deleteButton" value="Delete">`;
    
    document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0].append(createdTask);
    // console.log(tasks.length);
})

//code from here does not work. This is the code for deletion
var del= document.getElementsByClassName("deleteButton");

for(let i=0;i<del.length;i++){
    del[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        for(var j=0;j<tasks.length;j++){
            if(tasks[j].name==del[i].id){
                tasks.splice(j, 1);
                console.log("hello");
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I am not able to delete task from array using class name and splice function. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Create a complete snippet with tools `[<>]` thanks.

Comment: Please include the necessary code for a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot magically guess what you're doing / trying to do.

Comment: Done. Pls check now.

Comment: You haven't created a proper snippet - I'm going to edit to convert your code into a snippet; please add your html to the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

How about instead of looping the elements, but attach the event handler to document. Like so:

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
   if(e.target && e.target.className  == 'deleteButton'){
     e.target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.target.parentNode)
     tasks.splice(tasks.findIndex(({name}) => name == e.target.parentNode.id), 1);
   }
});
```

> PS: Note that giving id as taskName `createdTask.id= taskName;`may not be the best practice.